# opencv simpleblobdetector - get blob attributes for identified blobs

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the simpleblobdetector from opencv with python to identify blobs in an image.

I'm able to get the simple blob detector to work and give me the locations of identified blobs. But can I also get the inertia/convexity/circularity/etc properties of identified blobs?

```
img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# set up blob detector params
detector_params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
detector_params.filterByInertia = True
detector_params.minInertiaRatio = 0.001
detector_params.filterByArea = True
detector_params.maxArea = 10000000
detector_params.minArea = 1000
detector_params.filterByCircularity = True
detector_params.minCircularity = 0.0001
detector_params.filterByConvexity = True
detector_params.minConvexity = 0.01

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(detector_params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(img)

# print properties of identified blobs
for p in keypoints:
    print(p.pt) # locations of blobs
    # circularity???
    # inertia???
    # area???
    # convexity???
    # etc...
```

Thanks

Comment: besides `p.pt` you can also get the `p.size`, not sure if that helps

Answer (score 2):

The keypoints returned by the detector do not contain any information about the algorithm that found them, as per [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html):

> cv::KeyPoint: Data structure for salient point detectors.
>
> The class instance stores a keypoint, i.e. a point feature found by
> one of     many available keypoint detectors, such as Harris corner
> detector, cv::FAST, cv::StarDetector, cv::SURF, cv::SIFT,
> cv::LDetector etc.
>
> The keypoint is characterized by the 2D position, scale (proportional
> to the diameter of the neighborhood that needs to be taken into
> account), orientation and some other parameters.

You can draw the keypoints, showing size and rotation:

```
img = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, None, color=(0,255,0), flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

Comment: Too bad, it would be helpful in parameterization.

Comment: I still cannot wrap my head around all this. Just detecting a blob and it's location might be enough for some scenarios but there are so many others where things like size (in my case I am using the detector to detect pores in a membrane and calculate each pore's diameter) would be very helpful.

Comment: I agree with @rbaleksandar this is extremely frustrating since the blob detector clearly computes all these values, but simply doesn't return them. I'd much rather that the blob detector returns the keypoints with all these parameters and then filter them out myself by hand, I know that matlab has this functionality but I'd much rather stay within python ....